# Blackberry WebWorks HTML5 Database Issues

Tags: html, sqlite, blackberry, mobile, blackberry-webworks

I've been having lots of problems getting my application to work using an sqlite database. Everything works just fine in ripple (I presume this is because it's just using chrome's sqlite implementation). However, once I run my app on a simulator (Curve 9300, OS 6) the problems begin. I've gotten to where the app can run, create a database, and insert rows, so I know that my actual queries are fine.

My application has a javascript file that has wrappers for working with the database. This javascript file is sourced in both the listener, and the page that is the core of the application. The problem is as follows:

1. Install the application. The listener starts running.
2. Send a text message from one simulator to another. The message is saved successfully (I can verify this because my banner indicator count increases, and the number is based of off a query)
3. Continue sending texts, and the banner indicator will increase.
4. Open the application, and read all of the messages. At this point, the javascript file is loaded twice, so I have two db objects pointing to the same database.
5. Close the application (listener is still running)
6. The next text message received causes a Runtime Exception, with no further details provided.

I looked at the stack trace, and it just says that the exception took place in the callback of the sms listener. This is obvious, as that's where the queries happen. Does anyone have any idea why opening a second connection to the db causes the exception? As far I understand, the db is only locked during a transaction. There are definitely no transactions running, other than the one trying to insert the new row. Although I'm new to javascript, I'm quite sure that no variables are being shared as the javascript file is loaded in two different pages. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't find a solution. I don't think the blackberry sqlite implementation can handle two concurrent connections. Instead, my listener now saves incoming data to a file. The file is read in when the main application opens, and all necessary data is saved to the db then. Afterwards, the file is deleted and the application performs queries without problem. I hope this helps anyone dealing with a similar issue.